# Can't figure why "jQuery File Upload " plugin isn't working

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

For the past hour I am trying to get [jQuery plugin](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) to work.

What i can't resolve is this js error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fileupload is not a function`, 
I tried a lot of things.. i even downloaded the js files from the demo site and still this error appear,

How can i solve it? 
this is my js file(as you can see the pluging is getting called only when dom is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fileUpload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

this is my .cshtml (i am using asp.net mvc) code file:

```
<h2>Index</h2>

<!-- Bootstrap styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- blueimp Gallery styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
<!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
<link href="~/Assets/plugins/jqueryFileUpload/css/jquery.fileupload.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Assets/plugins/jqueryFileUpload/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- CSS adjustments for browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
<link href="~/Assets/plugins/jqueryFileUpload/css/jquery.fileupload-noscript.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Assets/plugins/jqueryFileUpload/css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<input type='file' multiple id='fileUpload' name="files[]" data-url="@Url.Action("Upload","Home")" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="~/Assets/plugins/jqueryFileUpload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Templates/js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- blueimp Gallery script -->
<script src="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="~/Assets/plugins/jqueryFileUpload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="~/Assets/plugins/jqueryFileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
<script src="~/Assets/plugins/jqueryFileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
<script src="~/Assets/plugins/jqueryFileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload audio preview plugin -->
<script src="~/Assets/plugins/jqueryFileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload video preview plugin -->
<script src="~/Assets/plugins/jqueryFileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-video.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload validation plugin -->
<script src="~/Assets/plugins/jqueryFileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload user interface plugin -->
<script src="~/Assets/plugins/jqueryFileUpload/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>

<script src="~/Assets/scripts/js.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is your jquery loaded properly? Make sure your jquery is loaded before the fileupload

Comment: it is loaded properly, it is the first thing i load. + the error is not related to jquery.. it is related to the plug-in

Comment: why do you have an input before your script files? Im sure that wouldnt work if your JS files havent been loaded yet

Comment: you need to use http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js to load the jquery

Comment: @RanjithS see the first <script> tag, jquery is loaded

Comment: make sure that your script source path are getting generated correctly. You can test it by opening your page in browser -> then view source of web page-> then go to any  js file like `jquery.fileupload.js` and click on it. See whether you are getting complete JS source code of it or not. I think there is problem with `src="~/Assets/plugins/` tilda.

Comment: Just pass the $ in document.ready like jQuery(document).ready(function($){

//file upload code here

});

Comment: @Chris , i have posted the content of my JS file. the call for the plugin is occurring only when the dom finished loading.

Comment: Try passing the $ symbol in `ready(function($)`

Comment: @vijayP i checked for the console in google chrome and this is the only error that i get.. + i have checked the content of the CDN jquery file.
its all OK

Comment: maybe check that you load the files in the correct order. Try moving the `fileupload-ui.js` JS file just below `fileupload.js`

Comment: @Chris, yes I already did that + i copied the exact order + js files from the example website - and it didn't work

Comment: Can someone here try it himself? please:)

Comment: @EranMeir - could you please check browser's network section too and see if all files are getting downloaded correctly.

Comment: @vijayP, i checked it now. its all ok..

Comment: After changing `$(document).ready(function () {` to `$(document).load(function () {` the error disappeared. Try that and let us know if it helped?

Comment: @Chris, great , its is working now.. post it as an answer, so if its happen to someone else- he will know what to do.. Thanks. do you know why? in the demo site it is working with ready()

Comment: @EranMeir I have no idea. Initially I thought I has to wait for the document to load but since you said it works in the demo site I really dont know. Ill do some investigation and post my findings here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After changing

`$(document).ready(function ( ... ) {`

to

`$(document).load(function ( ... ) {`

the error disappeared.

Comment: Worked great for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check console in Firebug Inspect element some error not show in console.

I think some files are not loaded on your webpage or path of file are not found in webpage so that why this error is happened.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was with duplicate call to jquery.min.js script